# How to get jq to print valid json after applying a filter

Tags: json, bash, shell, amazon-web-services, jq

I'm working on jq filtering and output of results to output into another program that accepts a JSON payload. Consider the following example:

INPUT:

```
My-MBP:myorg myname$ aws ec2 describe-snapshots --owner-id 12345678 | jq '.Snapshots[] | select(.Description | contains("myorg-database-b"))'
```

RESULT:

```
{
  "Description": "myorg-database-b redacted",
  "Encrypted": false,
  "VolumeId": "vol-1234",
  "State": "completed",
  "VolumeSize": 500,
  "StartTime": "2018-08-28T17:52:14.000Z",
  "Progress": "100%",
  "OwnerId": "12345678",
  "SnapshotId": "snap-2424"
}
{
  "Description": "myorg-database-b redacted",
  "Encrypted": false,
  "VolumeId": "vol-23456",
  "State": "completed",
  "VolumeSize": 500,
  "StartTime": "2018-08-28T19:01:18.000Z",
  "Progress": "100%",
  "OwnerId": "12345678",
  "SnapshotId": "snap-5535"
}
```

No matter what I try to do, I can't get `jq` to print valid JSON so that I can pipe it into another program.

The original JSON from AWS was an array of objects, why can't I get back a valid array of objects? Am I doing something wrong here?

Here is what the AWS payload looks like before it gets piped into `jq`:

```
{
    "Snapshots": [
        {
            "Description": "myorg-database-b redacted",
            "Encrypted": false,
            "VolumeId": "vol-23456",
            "State": "completed",
            "VolumeSize": 500,
            "StartTime": "2018-08-28T19:01:18.000Z",
            "Progress": "100%",
            "OwnerId": "12345678",
            "SnapshotId": "snap-5535"
        }, 
        {
            "Description": "myorg-database-b redacted",
            "Encrypted": false,
            "VolumeId": "vol-23456",
            "State": "completed",
            "VolumeSize": 500,
            "StartTime": "2018-08-28T19:01:18.000Z",
            "Progress": "100%",
            "OwnerId": "12345678",
            "SnapshotId": "snap-5535"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Question, if the AWS response is valid json, why do you want to pipe it via jq? You may feed what you want to feed with the direct AWS response maybe.

Comment: What's the output you're trying to get?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can wrap the entire jq expression into square brackets to make it collect the filter output into an array (documented in [Array construction section](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Arrayconstruction:[])):

```
'[ .Snapshots[] | select(.Description | contains("myorg-database-b")) ]'
```

results in:

```
[
  {
    "Description": "myorg-database-b redacted",
    "Encrypted": false,
    "VolumeId": "vol-23456",
    "State": "completed",
    "VolumeSize": 500,
    "StartTime": "2018-08-28T19:01:18.000Z",
    "Progress": "100%",
    "OwnerId": "12345678",
    "SnapshotId": "snap-5535"
  },
  {
    "Description": "myorg-database-b redacted",
    "Encrypted": false,
    "VolumeId": "vol-23456",
    "State": "completed",
    "VolumeSize": 500,
    "StartTime": "2018-08-28T19:01:18.000Z",
    "Progress": "100%",
    "OwnerId": "12345678",
    "SnapshotId": "snap-5535"
  }
]
```

Comment: that's it! believe it or not I've been RTFMing the man page and searching google but that was not easily found or known! thanks!

Comment: It's explained in the [array construction section](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Arrayconstruction:[]) of jq manual.